# Make the value of a select box the same as the name of the option without copy paste

Tags: php

my question is how can I replace all the values with the option name without copy paste. 
The new list will be happen once, so that it can help me to win hours of copy-paste.

It's been a puzzle to me. Thanks for your solutions and ideas.

```
<option value="61">Talbot</option>
<option value="3830">Tata</option>
<option value="248">Toyota</option>
<option value="63">Trabant</option>
<option value="64">Triumph</option>
<option value="651">Uaz</option>
```

This is an example of what I want

```
<option value="Talbot">Talbot</option>
```

Comment: In what context?  If this needs to happen on a page, PHP isn't required.  Some quick jQuery can select the `option` elements, iterate over each of them, and set their `.val()` to their `.text()`.  Or does this need to happen once on a long list?  Or on the server-side for a specific reason?  Please provide more context.

Comment: @David Hi There, the list will happen once so I will implement it correctly to my script. I have like thousands of these and my purpose is to produce them like `<option value="Talbot">Talbot</option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with PHP you should use preg_replace() function
It will look something like this:

```
<?php
$ptn    = "/<option value=\"(.*)\">(.*)<\/option>/";
$str    = '<option value="61">Talbot</option>';
$rpltxt = '<option value="$2">$1</option>';
echo preg_replace($ptn, $rpltxt, $str);
?>
```

output will be:

```
<option value="Talbot">61</option>
```

Comment: Hello Hektor, I want the option value to be the same as the option name like `<option value="Talbot">Talbot</option>`

Comment: so replace $rpltxt variable with this:
`$rpltxt = '<option value="$2">$2</option>';`

Answer (score 0):

because most people do interesting things with whitespace, case, and quotes, there are few guarantees.

a proper search regex would look like

```
"/<[oO][pP][tT][iI][oO][nN]\s+[vV][aA][lL][uU][eE]\s*=\s*['\"]?(.*)['\"]?\s*>(.*)</[oO][pP][tT][iI][oO][nN]>/"

replace with "<option value=\"$2\">$2</option>"
```

the first set of perens are not required (but the .* is).